# ratio of non diastatic malt powder to one pound of flour.

Tags: bread

So I have to make bagels tomorrow. For 50 lbs of flour the recipe calls for 2.5 lbs of this super bagel mix which my boss forgot to order. Tasting it its most likely salt sugar and malt...maybe something else too.I can figure out the salt and sugar but have never used malt in baking.I am assuming that it is non diastatic only because it is mixed in with flour. Hopefully not assuming to much.
 So the question is what is the ratio or rule for non diastatic malt powder to flour.

Answer (score 3):

The [King Arthur Flour bagel recipe](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/water-bagels-recipe), the only one I could find that used non-diastatic malt power instead of malt syrup, has a ratio of 5.75 cups of flour to 1/4 cup malt powder to 2Tbs sugar and 1 Tbs salt.

By weight, that works out to a Flour:Malt:Sugar:Salt ratio of 25:1.4:0.8:0.6.  So for 50lbs of flour, you'd want:

- 2.8lbs malt powder
- 1.6lbs sugar
- 1.2lbs salt

... which is a bit more than the "super bagel mix" of 2.5 lbs, in fact more that twice as much.  You can cut the amounts in half, but I'm not sure that will work out.  Good luck!